# MongoDB storing data in two different locations

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm sort of new at MongoDB and running into a few problems with locating/accessing data that I've created or imported, in that it's ending up in two distinct locations.

If I start the shell like this

```
 $ mongo
```

and then show the databases

```
$ show dbs
```

this gives me a list of about 10 databases that I've created. These are in the /data/db directory It does not include a db called 'pact'

However, if I connect like this

```
$ mongo localhost/pact
```

and then do

```
 $show dbs
```

it only lists one db, the `pact` db, which isn't listed when I connect to mongo the other way by just doing 'mongo.' 'Pact' isn't in the /data/db directory.  According to my  notes, I might have made the 'pact' db by starting mongod this way,

```
mongod --dbpath data
```

which I would think would position it in the data/db directory, and I imported into the pact directory like this

```
mongoimport --stopOnError --db pact --collection products <  products.json
```

Moving on, if I use mongo in irb and start like this

```
>> mongo_client = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
```

and then do 'show dbs'

I get the long list of dbs from the /data/db directory (which didn't include pact).

In order to find db `pact` through irb, I tried to include it after localhost, as I do with mongo localhost/pact

```
>> mongo_client = MongoClient.new("localhost/pact", 27017)
```

but I got an error.

1 Is there a way I can find out what directory the 'pact' db is in?

2 How can I access it in irb with the Mongo driver if not by

> > mongo_client = MongoClient.new("localhost/pact", 27017)

which I assumed would work since I can do this in the shell `mongo localhost/pact`

3 Based on what I've told you, can you explain why this happened (I'm assuming it's not the proper way to have data saved in another directory)

Comment: Did you turn on authentication?  Could you be using cached credentials for one connection but not the other? You do have only one mongo process running, right?

Comment: only one process is running. I've never deliberately turned on authentication. I don't know anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use `mongodump` in `mongo localhost/pact` shell context

```
mongodump -d pact -o /out/dir
```

to backup the entire database. And use `mongorestore` at normall `mongo` shell context

```
mongorestore -d pact /out/dir
```

to restore the database.